# PHP - saving data with foreign key (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables, `users` and `onlineform` in my db. `onlineform` have a field called `userid` which is a foreign key to `users` table `id`. When im saving data to `onlineform` table, im trying to save the logged in user id to `userid` field. But, it only returned this `Message:  Undefined index: userid`. The confusing part is other data can be saved, only user id cant be save to the `userid` field in `onlineform` table. Im using ajax to save my data

my model, **form_model.php**

```
public function save($form_data) 
{
    for ($i=0; $i < count($form_data); $i++) { 
        $data[] = array(
            'id'=>$form_data[$i]['userid'],
            'date'=>$form_data[$i]['date'],
            'day'=>$form_data[$i]['day'],
            'in1'=>$form_data[$i]['in1'],
            'out1'=>$form_data[$i]['out1'],
            'in2'=>$form_data[$i]['in2'],
            'out2'=>$form_data[$i]['out2'],
        );
    }

    try {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($form_data); $i++) {
            $this->db->insert('onlineform',$data[$i]);
        }
        return 'success';
    } 

    catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'failed';
    }

}
```

controller, **form.php**

```
public function save()
{
    $form_data = $this->input->post('form_table');

    $this->load->model('form_model');
    $status = $this->form_model->save($form_data);

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'status'));
}
```

and my view, **report.php**

```
$('#savedb').click(function(){

        var form_table = [];
        $('#form_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {

            if ($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text() == "") {
            }

            else {
                var sub = {
                    'day' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    'date' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    'in1' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    'out1' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    'in2' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    'out2' : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    'id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
                };
                form_table.push(sub);
            }
        });

        var data = {
            'form_table' :form_table
        };

        $.ajax({
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            url : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/Form/save'); ?>',
            crossOrigin : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(result) {
                if(result.status == "success"){
                }

                else {
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$form_data[$i]['userid']` should be `$form_data[$i]['id']`

as is defined here:

```
'id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
```

OR change the later to: `'userid' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()`

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much. very silly mistake. the id and userid should be change